# VB line of code inquiry, filed = (variable = 0)

Tags: vb.net, saleslogix

I am working with our CRM program and coding some stuff into the system. I kind of get the basics, but I am not fully familiar with it so I am stuck trying to understand what this line means and what it actually does. Any help is truly appreciated.

Code looks something like this:

```
txtField.ReadOnly = (intOption = 0)
SetControlColor(txtField)
```

I know what intOption is, and I know what the outcome of the code is doing, but I don't understand what this line truly does...

Answer (score 3):

Tear it apart. Read it from right to left. This part of the line:

```
(intOption = 0)
```

is comparing whether `intOption` equals `0`. This will return `True` or `False`. That `True` or `False` value will then be assigned to `txtField.ReadOnly`, which is a `Boolean` type.

It is equivalent to this code:

```
If intOption = 0 Then
    txtField.ReadOnly = True
Else
    txtField.ReadOnly = False
End If
```

As you can see, it is easier to write all that code into one line.